# Are some things too simple for us to understand?

Tags: epistemology

Everyone has at some point identified some things as too complicated for them to understand.

Might some things be to simple for humans to understand?  Might it be that some geniuses have an ability to understand immensely simple things out of reach of most of us, but many other things are too simple for them?

Might some philosophical problems match that description?  Might perhaps the "hard problem" of consciousness be of that sort?

Comment: I don't see what "simplicity" means here. Can you perhaps furnish some examples of simple theories, or simple explanations?

Comment: I *think* that 'simple' in this question might be from the definition "plain, basic, or uncomplicated in form, nature, or design; without much decoration or ornamentation."     is there something so uncomplicated in form that humans can't understand it?       Possibly in this case the concept of nothingness is hard to comprehend

Comment: though arguably that is not "Some thing"

Comment: "Simple" should mean lacking complications; involving not many things.

Comment: I think this question is more a cognitive sciences question than a philosophy one. I know that certain forms of anxiety and depression take on the form of people "overcomplicating" things, which translates in a cognitive disability of seeing tasks in a simple way.

Comment: Although I see problems in the formulating, I think this question is perfectly on topic as there have been a) philosophical positions claiming that others are oversophisticating things, making the simple unconceivable, and therefore formulating rather simple theories (sense data theories, naive realists, reductionalism in general) and b) philosophical positions claiming that in the genius, there lies the strength of seeing things as simple/unitary as they indeed are (e.g. German Idealism, Romanticism). Therefore I vote to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Two things come to mind:

1. Kants noumena might be suggested as too simple to understand; it lacks differentiation and by such a lack there is nothing for the mind to grasp.
2. Axioms, or correlatively clear and distinct ideas, lie at the foundations of thought and being foundational there is nothing more that can be said about them.